# Django - database order_id bug

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, tensorflow, django-models

I have a app in Django, that has models.py like that:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import base64





class Order(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    #note = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=45)


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=32)


    #name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    #access_to_doors = models.ManyToManyField(Door, blank=True)


class Review(models.Model):
    review_id = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    review_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    #username = models.ManyToManyField(Users)




class Contact(models.Model):
    email=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password=models.CharField(null=True, max_length=32)
    subject=models.CharField(null=True, max_length=1024)
   #def __str__(self):
    #    return self.email
```

I delete database, make a new one, run

```
python manage.py migrate/makemigrations/migrate --run-syncdb
```

and it says this

```
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying building_access.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 74, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'order_id' used in key specification without a key length")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 233, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 92, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 324, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 74, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "D:\dev\building_access\myvenv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'order_id' used in key specification without a key length")
```

So as it generated like 1/3rd of the database I went over to mysql workbench to fix the order_id table. Now, I have not found a single order_iq table in my database nor my project. I've tried making  database over and over, I've tried deleting Order class from models.py.

Comment: It is not a table, it is a *column*.

Comment: column is in table, I didn't find any colum fitting this name.